# Binding a Form to an Object Ruby on Rails Sending an instance from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms, has-many

I have company model with devise authentication installed on it. It has_many :jobs.

My goal is to successfully create a job record when I am signed in as that existing company and have it be properly linked in my mongoid databse.

I want one form to update multiple models.

I know how to set

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs, allow_destroy: true
```

but I am having trouble passing that instance from my controller to the nested form ?

in my companies controller I have this

```
def new 
    @company = current_company.jobs.new()
  end

  def create
    #the actual create process where the params from the forms got sent here
    @company = current_company.jobs.new(params[:company])
  end
```

and here is my form

```
<%= simple_form_for @company do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :jobs do |j| %>
    <%= j.input :title %>
    <%= j.input :description %>
  <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I send the current company jobs object to the view and have it posted correctly?
currently in the form when I hit submit I am creating an empty job object. The values are not getting there?

I think the devise authentication on the company model complicated a lot of things. I did it in another time but without authentication.

if I change the controller to this

```
def new 

@company = Company.new 

end 

def create
    #the actual create process where the params from the forms got sent here
    @company = Company.new(params[:company])
 end
```

If I am signed in as a company then I am getting 'you are already signed in' if I am not signed in I am redirected to the devise registration path .

Comment: are the params coming in? `puts params.inspect` in your controller

Comment: @Jngai1297 the problem is in your controller & view. In new and create action you're initializing a job object not the company object. `@company` is an object of Job model with `company_id = current_company.id`. So in the view you do not need fields_for. And you will never get `params[:company]` values for this code.

Comment: @ManojMonga I do want the job to be created with that company's id. So should I do it in my jobs controller then? so I can have the same job object with `company_id = current_company.id` ?  so I move the controller code to jobs controller?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion on your earlier post?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need build() instead of new():

```
def new 
  @company = current_company
  @company.jobs.build()
end

def create
  #the actual create process where the params from the forms got sent here
  @job = current_company.jobs.build(params[:company][:job_attributes])

  if @job.save
     # redirect somewhere
  else
     render :new
  end
end
```